# Coding the card game "War" in C

Tags: c, linked-list, playing-cards

I am coding the card game War in C. I am having some difficulty with my code. I am getting the following errors:

```
main.c:167:17: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘shufflepile’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  167 |     shufflepile(a, n); //shuffle array elements
      |                 ^
      |                 |
      |                 struct node **
main.c:159:23: note: expected ‘link’ {aka ‘struct node *’} but argument is of type ‘struct node **’
  159 | link shufflepile(link pile) {
      |                  ~~~~~^~~~
main.c:167:5: error: too many arguments to function ‘shufflepile’
  167 |     shufflepile(a, n); //shuffle array elements
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~
main.c:159:6: note: declared here
  159 | link shufflepile(link pile) {
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

The code has been tested and is working properly through the "// Creating the 52 card deck" section.

I am very new to coding and am attempting to follow the code given in a lecture, so I am not sure what is causing my errors. Any help or feedback is appreciated.

The entire code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>


// Initiate deck of cards, normal 52 card deck (ace is high)

#define DECKSIZE 52

typedef int Card;

int rank(Card c) {
    return c % 13;
}

// allow for multi-deck war
int suit(Card c) {
    return (c % 52) / 13;
}

// representing the cards

void showcard(Card c) {
    switch (rank(c)) {
        case 0: printf("Deuce of "); break;
        case 1: printf("Three of "); break;
        case 2: printf("Four of "); break;
        case 3: printf("Five of "); break;
        case 4: printf("Six of "); break;
        case 5: printf("Seven of "); break;
        case 6: printf("Eight of "); break;
        case 7: printf("Nine of "); break;
        case 8: printf("Ten of "); break;
        case 9: printf("Jack of "); break;
        case 10: printf("Queen of "); break;
        case 11: printf("King of "); break;
        case 12: printf("Ace of "); break;
    }

    switch (suit(c)) {
    case 0: printf("Clubs\n"); break;
    case 1: printf("Diamonds\n"); break;
    case 2: printf("Hearts\n"); break;
    case 3: printf("Spades\n"); break;
    }
}
// testing the code


// representing the deck and hands (with linked lists because need direct access to top and bottom cards, draw cards from top, won cards go to bottom)

typedef struct node* link;
struct node {
    Card card;
    link next;
};

link Atop, Abot;
link Btop, Bbot;

// showing a hand

void showpile(link pile) {
    struct node *p;
    for (p = pile; p != NULL; p = p->next)
        showcard(p->card);
}

int countpile(link pile) {
    struct node *p;
    int cnt = 0;
    for (p = pile; p != NULL; p = p->next)
        cnt++;
    return cnt;
}

// Creating the 52 card Deck

#include <stdlib.h> //for malloc()

link NEWnode(Card card, link next) {
    struct node *p;
    p = malloc(sizeof *p); //allocate memory
    if (p == NULL) {
        perror("malloc");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    p->next = next;
    p->card = card;
    return p;
}

link makepile(int N) {
    struct node *p = NULL;
    Card c;

    for (c = N - 1; c >= 0; c--)
        p = NEWnode(c, p);

    return p;
}

// dealing the cards

link Atop, Abot, Btop, Bbot;

 void deal(link d) {
     Atop = d; Abot = d; d = d->next;
     Btop = d; Bbot = d; d = d->next;
     while (d != NULL) {
         Abot->next = d; Abot = d; d = d->next;
         Bbot->next = d; Bbot = d; d = d->next;
     }
     Abot->next = NULL; Bbot->next = NULL;
 }

 int main(void) {
     link deck;
    deck = makepile(DECKSIZE);
    deal(deck);
    printf("PLAYER A\n");
    showpile(Atop);
    printf("\nPLAYER B\n");
    showpile(Btop);
    return 0;
}

// shuffling the deck

link shufflepile(link pile) {
    int i, n;
    struct node *p;
    link a[DECKSIZE];

    for (p = pile, n = 0; p != NULL; p = p->next, n++)
        a[n] = p;

    shufflepile(a, n); //shuffle array elements

    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
        a[i]->next = a[i + 1];
    a[n-1]->next = NULL;

    return a[0];
}
```

The lecture used "shuffle(a, n)" instead of "shufflepile(a, n)" but this created an undeclared "shuffle" error, so I changed it to shufflepile.

Comment: Have you modified the code in any way, or is it a straight copy-paste from the lecture?

Comment: The lecture has "shuffle(a, n)" instead of "shufflepile(a, n)" but that produces an error that says shuffle not defined, or something like that. Also, the lecture is a powerpoint that has the code broken up on different slides, so it is very possible I have made multiple mistakes.

Comment: No doubt this was copied from the lecture, but it is very poor style to hide pointer nature behind a typedef (*i.e.* `link`).  This tends much more to confuse and obfuscate than to clarify.  At least one of the errors in the program is associated with this issue.

Comment: You probably have made some mistakes in your copy-paste. Any possible `shuffle` function is very different from `shufflepile`. There are also many other mistakes in the code, it's going to be impossible to tell which mistakes are because of possibly bad code in the lecture, and possible mistakes made when copy-pasting.

Comment: I have heard people say it is poor style to hide pointer nature behind a typedef. I am new to programming so I am not sure why this is the case. Could anyone briefly explain this?

Comment: Declare your variable as `struct node *p;` instead of `link x;` It's clear that `p` is a pointer.

Comment: ... which, as I already said, tends much more to confuse (humans) than to clarify to them.  And clarity and ease for humans is the *only* purpose of `typedef` -- it is syntactic sugar, which a C programmer who is so inclined can altogether avoid using in their own code.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear why you are using linked list for this exercise. You are not adding or removing elements from the list, it's easier to use `malloc` to allocate 52 cards.

If, for example, you are dealing cards from this deck, then you do need to use, say two linked list, add cards from the deck to these linked lists, or you want to remove cards from main deck.

To do this, the linked list has to have add/remove functions. See examples of linked list to get familiar with this.

Note, `typedef` might be useful in some cases, for example compatibility with c++, but you don't have to worry about that. If you must use `typedef` you can declare it as

```
typedef struct node link;
```

Then use declare `link *ptr;` in your code. Otherwise stick with `struct node *ptr;` You have to `free` all memory allocated by `malloc`. This example shows to produce one deck of cards and shuffle it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void print(int* deck, int count)
{
    const char* faces[] = { "Club", "Diamond", "Heart", "Spade" };
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        printf("%02d of %s\n", 1 + deck[i] % 13, faces[deck[i] / 13]);
}

void shuffle(int* deck, int count)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        //swap two cards
        int m = rand() % count;
        int n = rand() % count;
        int temp = deck[m];
        deck[m] = deck[n];
        deck[n] = temp;
    }
}

int main()
{
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    int count = 52; //52 cards
    int* deck = malloc(count * sizeof(int));
    if (!deck) { perror("malloc"); return 0; }
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        deck[i] = i;
    print(deck, count); 
    shuffle(deck, count);
    print(deck, count);
    free(deck); //release memory
    return 0;
}
```